# Change innerHTML color randomly in loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a loop that will continuously change the color by randomly generating hex codes. I tried to search on here but couldn't find anything doing this.

I can't figure out how to get a loop to run and change the color continuously (until the end of a loop). I am new to JavaScript.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/kkfnjpsh).

### HTML

```
<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="test">Generate colors.</div>
</div>
</body>
```

## JS

```
for ( i = 0; i < 20000; i++ ) {
    var t = document.getElementById('test');
    var z = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    t.style.color = z
}
```

Comment: That `for` loop is going to execute insanely fast, and most likely look like it never even changes colors, FYI

Comment: Since `t` isn't changing, you can assign it outside the loop.

Comment: @tymeJV When I try to increase the duration of the loop (make i < 20000000, etc..) it just takes longer to display the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change colors in a loop, the color of the element won't change until you exit the code and return control to the browser.

You can use an interval to run code and return the control to the browser each time:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var t = document.getElementById('test');
  var z = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  t.style.color = z
}, 100);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/et3qtr3t/

Comment: That was it! Appreciate it. Do you know where I can find some documentation that says the element color won't be able to change? I was looking for a little while.. Will accept when the timer expires

Comment: @OverMind the for loop runs Y loops over X time, meaning each loop takes time c = Y/X (approximately). Even if c were longer than it takes to access the DOM and perform a change, each change would last for so little that you wouldn't notice.

Comment: @OverMind: Looking for information about the event loop will get you some information about this. For example this, not so clear on the implications, but a start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

Comment: @royhowie: That is right, but it's not the reason. If you loop for a long time then some changes would be visible even if you would miss the vast majority of them. The browser simply freezes while the code is running, so nothing is shown until after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You were right with the commented `setInterval` you have on fiddle. It will make the colors change periodically (according to the milliseconds defined).

But you have to remove the `for` loop, because it will run instantly and you won't even see the changes... You'll have to manage your own variable counter, and clear the interval after it:

http://jsfiddle.net/kkfnjpsh/5/

```
var i = 0;
var runner = setInterval(function(){
    if(i < 20000) {
        var t = document.getElementById('test');
        var z = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        t.style.color = z;
        i++;
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(runner);
    }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already been answered, but mine includes the cleartimeout to set a timer.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){changeColor()}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(myVar)}, 5000);
```

The second argument in the call to setTimeout could serve as your timer, so that the animation stops afterwards, in this case, it's set to 5 seconds.

```
function changeColor() {
    var t = document.getElementById('test');
    var z = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    t.style.color = z;
    console.log(z);
}
```

Result: [Result](http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/kkfnjpsh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't loop - you interval:

```
var target= document.getElementById('test'),
colorChange = function() {
    target.style.color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
};

// run interval
var d = setInterval(function() {

     colorChange();
}, 500);

// clear after 5s

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(d);
}, 5000);
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/046q6ohf/